# What happens when you are conscious but not stabilized?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions, hit-points

I was creating some condition cards when I noticed that... (all quotes from the [SRD](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Conditions&Category=Combat))

- You are *dying* if you have negative HP<sup>1</sup>, you have **not stabilized** and you are **not conscious**.

  > A dying creature is **unconscious** and near death. [...] The character must make a DC 10 Constitution check **to become stable**
- You are *stable* if you have negative HP<sup>1</sup>, you have stabilized and you are **not conscious**.

  > A character **who was dying but who has stopped losing hit points each round** and still has negative hit points is stable. The character is no longer dying, **but is still unconscious**.
- You are *disabled* if you have 0 HP or if you have Negative HP<sup>1</sup>, you have stabilized and you are conscious.

  > A character with 0 hit points, or one who has negative hit points **but has become stable and conscious**, is disabled.

What happens to a character who ends up in negative HP and conscious **without having stabilized?**

---

A note on [Ferocity](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Ferocity): Ferocity happens when you would end up being Dying, and it prevents you from being unconscious while still being Dying, which means  this situation exists, but it's not clear if the HP loss is the one of Dying (and can be stopped by stabilizing) or it's just a non-stabilizable form of the same. It even goes as far as to say that you're **still** Staggered, but you were never staggered to begin with. Anyway, it looks like it has special exception-based rules and it's not trying to explain a general case.

---

1. But less than your Constitution score, otherwise you'd be dead

Comment: One fairly straightforward answer would be [Ferocity](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Ferocity). Are you looking for things like this or are you more interested in the general "state machine" of dying?

Comment: @MrLemon I'm interested in the "state machine" and, given that you've now proven that it's an achievable status, I've removed that part of the question (it was there just to say "hey, maybe we don't need a status because it never happens")

Comment: RE: "What happens to a character who ends up in negative HP and conscious without having stabilized?" Is this a cause-and-effect question, or are you looking for a game element that enables this state? That is, is the question *Does a creature upon becoming stable lose the condition dying?* or *Is a creature that's still conscious at negative hp actually not dying?* or something? Or is this a scavenger hunt to make conscious-but-dying an achievable state?

Comment: Well I guess the answer is that he can only take a single action and loses 1 HP per round, since Ferocity exist the question is answered ''YES but you still lose 1 HP per  round and can only take one action''. The new question is ''Not including Ferocity Can you ever be conscious but not stabilized?''  Wich I couldn't answer, I don't know. Even DieHard makes you stable (but disabled).

Comment: @HeyICanChan I want to know how to rule this situation at the table. It already matters to me despite not having happened yed because I'm creating a set of condition cards and I don't want a rule hole in them. Please note that I reformulated the question with the exact purpose of removing the achievable state part, since it is achievable (as MrLemon found out).

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think the title I forgot to edit was causing the confusion, I have changed it to fit the question.

Answer (score 2):

That creature is still dying.

> A dying creature is unconscious and near death. **Creatures that have negative hit points and have not stabilized are dying.** A dying creature can take no actions. On the character’s next turn, after being reduced to negative hit points (but not dead), and on all subsequent turns, **the character must make a DC 10 Constitution check to become stable.** The character takes a penalty on this roll equal to his negative hit point total. A character that is stable does not need to make this check. A natural 20 on this check is an automatic success. If the character fails this check, he loses 1 hit point. If a dying creature has an amount of negative hit points equal to its Constitution score, it dies.

-- [Dying](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/conditions/#Dying)

The general rule seems pretty clear: if a creature has negative HP and isn't dead, they're dying, which means that they're unconscious and unstable.

Specific abilities can, of course, affect the "dying" state (eg., Ferocity removes the "unconscious" and "can take no actions" portions), but the default assumption about a live creature with negative HP is that they've either stabilized or need to do so before they bleed out.